# Utilizar un Distinct dentro de un Count

Tags: sql, distinct, count

Estoy intentando realizar un Count a una lista de registros de lecturas filtradas con un Distinct a los lectores.

Como ejemplo lo coloco así:

En una tabla de datos hay 100 registros de lecturas de un bloc. Estos registros tienen ID de los lectores, Titulo del post, y una fecha.

Lo que estoy queriendo que me traiga el Query es un conteo de cuantos lectores hay por día pero sin repetir el nombre de los lectores. Es decir que si Juan leyo 3 notas el 13 de Abril del 2021, me aparezca como un solo registro.

Hay que tener en cuenta que tengo una tabla llamada "Contactos" donde estan los nombres de los lectores y una tabla llamada "Historial de Visita" donde estan los registros de las visitas al bloc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tendrías que pasarle el filtro a COUNT()

```
SELECT COUNT ( DISTINCT column_name ) FROM table1 WHERE date = '2016-05-12';
```